# How to send/receive text messages online without ads attached to text?

Tags: php, api, text, sms

Need to send/receive text messages between user and system. Any solutions available online?

Is there any PHP API of Google voice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not use the email address provided by the phone company? 
(small sample list)

- ATT          [10-digit phone number]@txt.att.net
- Sprint       [10-digit phone number]@messaging.sprintpcs.com
- T-Mobile     [10-digit phone number]@tmomail.net
- US Cellular  [10-digit phone number]@email.uscc.net
- Verizon      [10-digit phone number]@vtext.com

Unless you are sending a text message to a number that you do not know the carrier.  Also, if you do use this method, the 1XX limit (I think it varies by carrier) still applies.  You message might be truncated or send it multiple parts (again depends on the carrier).  As far as I know this is the only free way to send a text message.

Comment: I know this method, but this is more like one-way communication. User cannot reply to sms, which is one of the requirements...

Comment: Sure they can, try sending an email to your phone and then replying.

Comment: cool! I wonder why I didn't even try to... probably because of weird number from which message comes from - 140000001 (att).. Thanks anyways! Now need to figure out how to parse the response...

Comment: by the way, I just tested with AT&T... are you sure that it will work with other carriers?

Comment: I'm not sure, I've never tried with a variety of carriers.  Start asking your friends if you can test on their phones!

Answer (score 0):

You pay for a propper SMS gateway subscription, thats why there is ads attached to free ones, to cover the cost of the service.

Comment: any services you would recommend? links?